# Import CSV file and Compare User Entry

Tags: java, csv, io, bufferedreader

Starting a project, and this irriating me. I think the code is okay, but I don't understand how to either return a record or parse the line.

I have a CSV file, which displays like this in Libra.

USER PASSWORD
Chris Password
Michelle Password
John Password

I am getting the user to enter their user and password, and then trying to compare those against the CSV to make sure that 1) the username exists and 2) if it does, that the password is correct. To be honest, part 2 isn't essential as it's not part of the spec but I want to do it, and I suspect it would be the same problem as what I am having anyway. As I said, I think the code is okay, but I'm not sure what format the variable thisLine will have and is my else statement moving the BufferedReader onto the next line correctly?

Can I use thisLine.trim() to cut USER PASSWORD does to just USER?

static void readFromCsvFile(String sFileName, User user) throws FileNotFoundException
       {
           String thisLine;

```
        try
        {
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sFileName));
           thisLine = reader.readLine();
           System.out.print(thisLine);

           while((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
               {
                    if (user.displayUserName() == thisLine)
                    {
                    System.out.print("\nUser <-" + user.displayUserName() + " -> exists!");
                    reader.close();
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        thisLine = reader.readLine();
                    }
               }

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.print("\nUser does not exist\n"); 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several remarks here:

1) `thisLine.trim()` will just remove the trailing blanks at the beginning and ending of the `thisLine` contents. It is okay to do so, specially if you are going to compare two strings, but it won't split the username and password from the variable.

2) To split the two different values you should use `thisLine.split(" ")` (I'm assuming that your CSV file uses blanks to separate the different fields).

3) Another mistake is to compare the strings using `==` rather than `equals`, which is the correct way of doing it.

4) Since you are reading a new line in the `while` condition you don't need the internal `reader.readLine()`

5) Finally, never close the stream (or reader) inside the loop!! Do it on a `try/catch/finally` block.

So, with those corrections your code will look like:

```
 static void readFromCsvFile(String sFileName, User user) throws FileNotFoundException { 
   String thisLine;
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sFileName));
    try
    {

       thisLine = reader.readLine();
       System.out.print(thisLine);

       while((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null)               
           {
               thisLine = thisLine.trim();
               String username = thisLine.split(" ")[0];
                if (user.displayUserName().equals(username))
                {
                System.out.print("\nUser <-" + user.displayUserName() + " -> exists!");
                break;   // break the loop
                }                    
           }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.print("\nUser does not exist\n"); 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { /* ignore */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers. Tried it but same problem! It terminates at the first line in the CSV file and won't move on. The first line will never be the correct one as it's just the headers.

Comment: Fixed it. I was using \t to separate records rather than ,

Answer (score 1):

To compare two String:

```
firstString.equal(secondString);
```

Another problem is `thisLine` contains username and password ("Chris Password" for example), so you must split your line to separate username ("Chris") and password ("Password").

```
while((thisLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    thisLine = thisLine.trim()
    // userData[0] => Username and userData[1] => Password
    String userData[] = thisLine.split(" ");
    if (user.displayUserName().equal(userData[0]))
    {
        System.out.print("\nUser <-" + user.displayUserName() + " -> exists!");
    }
}
```